# Entity Framework update with attach or single

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to entity framework and seeing different approaches for updating.

```
public void Update (Model model)
{
   var modelInDb = context.Singe(m => m.Id == model.Id);
   modelInDb.Name = "New Name";
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

```
public void Update (Model model)
{
   context.Customer.Attach(model);
   model.Name = "New Name";
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Why I should use attach over single? Could you explain difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing entities between client and server should be considered an antipattern because it can make your system vulnerable to man in the browser and similar attacks.

Your 2 examples don't really outline much because you are setting the updated value solely in your method, rather than based on input from the view. A more common example for an update would be:

```
public void Update (Model model)
{
   var modelInDb = context.Models.Singe(m => m.Id == model.Id);
   modelInDb.Name = model.Name;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and

```
public void Update (Model model)
{
   context.Models.Attach(model);
   context.Entity(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In your example, if your method sets the modifications then the UPDATE SQL statement should be Ok, just modifying the customer Name. However, if you attach the model, and set it's state to Modified to save the new model fields to the DB, it will update *all* columns.

Of these two examples, the first is better than the second for a number of reasons. The first example is loading the data from the context and copying across only the data you expect to be able to change from the view.  The second is taking the model from the view as-is, attaching it to the context, and will overwrite any existing fields. Attackers can discover this and use the behaviour to alter data your view did not allow to change. A customer Order for instance might contain a lot of data about an order including relationships for products, discounts, etc. A user may not see any of these details in their view, but by passing an Entity graph, all of it is visible in the web request data. Not only is this going to be sending far more information to the client than the client needs (slower) but it can be altered in debug tools and the like prior to reaching your service as well. Attaching and updating the returned entity exposes your system to tampering.

Additionally you risk overwriting stale data in your objects. With option 1 you are loading the "right now" copy of the entity. A simple check to a Row Version Number or Last Modified Date between your passed in data and the current DB copy can signal whether that row had changed since the copy passed to the client a while ago. With the 2nd method, you can inadvertently erase modifications to data without a trace.

The better approach is to pass ViewModels to and from your view. By using `Select` or Automapper to fill a view model, you avoid exposing any more about your domain than the client needs to see. You also only accept back the data needed for the operation the client can perform. This reduces the payload size and reduces the vulnerability to tampering. I've seen an alarming # of examples, even from Microsoft, passing Entities around between client and server. It looks practical since the objects are already there, but this is wasteful for resources/performance, troublesome for dealing with cyclic references and serialization, and prone to data tampering and stale data overwrites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very clear and in-depth.